# Are there any browser limits to the length of a line in HTML?

Tags: browser, html, web, html5

Do any browsers (Internet Explorer in particular) have bugs relating to the length of a line in HTML source code?

Assuming the source code is being optimised for HTML parsers/renderers and not for readability, and assuming any presentation/content whitespace has already been catered for, is there any reason to include line breaks between tags?

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers typically use any whitespace as a separator (1 or more whitespaces is treated the same as just one). It should not matter to the browser if there are no line breaks or carriage returns.

Edit:

While we cannot speak for all browsers and how they are implemented, let's look at the HTML 4 spec, [Section 9.1 for whitespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source
>   document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word
>   spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). In particular, user
>   agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing
>   output inter-word space. This can and should be done even in the
>   absence of language information (from the lang attribute, the HTTP
>   "Content-Language" header field (see [RFC2616], section 14.12), user
>   agent settings, etc.).
>
> The PRE element is used for preformatted text, where white space is
>   significant.

So in the vast majority of cases, if the browser is complaint with the spec, then it should render it how the spec describes (of course, the browser vendors have been known to use creative interpretation over time.)

Comment: Well of course it *should* not matter, but the question is: does it?

Comment: I would count the whitespace mentioned in Section 9.1 as presentation/content whitespace